# How to access all user settings from the google api?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to write scripts using the [Google Api nodejs client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/) which should change the GSuite settings of a user. Meaning all settings of the main google apps like gmail, gdrive, calendar and so on.

However I encountered that with the [google api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) I can only access a small portions of those settings.

For example, I want to change the "send cancelation period" to 10 seconds in the user`s Gmail setting. I could not find any resource in the [Gmail API Reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) which let me do that.

Is this just not possible or is there another way to access all the settings of a user?

Comment: If its not documented and you cant find it then its not supported.

Comment: but that is most of the settings a user can do. I am not sure if I am missing something...

Comment: Just because the user can do it in googles web application does not mean that they want developers doing it programmaticlly.  A lot of settings cant be changed by any api its a security thing.

Comment: Well I agree. But I am not talking about settings that can be a security thing. When you open the `general` tab of you gmail setting there are about 20 settings. But you only can change 2 of them...

Comment: another example are the calendar settings which can not be changed:https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings **that can be changed** by the APIs are referenced in the documentation. This one [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is indeed the appropriate one to look for the specific API and its methods - so if you haven't found the particular setting you want changed, it means that it **cannot** be changed by the API.

As a further matter, you can make use of [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) and file a `Feature Request` for a specific setting, for example.

**Reference**

- [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer);
- [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).